# What is "Isolation" and "Prominence" in mountain terms?

Tags: mountaineering, navigation, terminology

When I was browsing through the wikipedia page of the [Denali mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denali), I came across some piece of information.

Refer the screenshot below.

[image]

What does the term Prominence and Isolation mean?

Comment: **[Prominence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence)** and **[Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_isolation)** are links in the above screenshot. They're also purple, so you probably clicked them...

Comment: Mount Everest - Isolation = 40,008 km. I lol'd. (Explanation: 40,008 km is the circumference of the Earth, so you'd have to go that far in a "straight line" [great circle route] to circle around to the same peak again.) For the next few the isolation is probably just about the distance to one of the other mountains higher on the list.

Comment: @NickT: Yes I did, on my Cellphone, Reading it that way didn't make much a sense (as I was travelling). And, I strongly believe [wikipedia is not always the best way to get your answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Why_Wikipedia_is_not_so_great). Thats why we have forums like this one

Comment: @NickT What's the point here? I often ask questions here when I know an answer or some kind of answer. Still we want to get better answers and more infos on the topic collected in one thread. Also it helps other people and I like the idea to have a good knowledge base here. Really I don't get your point in trying to catch someone in *something* ...

Comment: @NickT It's even OK to ask a question and later answer it by yourself...

Comment: @NickT: Welcome to The Great Outdoors, by the way. You'll find plenty of question which could easily be answered if the person who asked (usually, we call OP) does a google search or read the wiki page. But then, here you get additional information through discussions, or even sometimes cross-points. Thats the beauty of this forum.

Comment: @NickT, as WedaPashi pointed out - this is perfectly fine to a) seek more information via other places, and b) ask and answer one's own question. The point of The Great Outdoors is to be a solid and high quality repository of information for future visitors, even if the question *&* answer is by the same person.

Comment: @WedaPashi FYI this site and network is not a forum but a Q&A site. Very different things.

Comment: @TylerH: Ok. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Isolation and prominence are the two key criteria to classify a peak as an independent mountain.

To understand the meaning I like the visualization from the [German Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominanz_%28Geographie%29) where

- "Dominanz" means **isolation** and
- "Schartenhöhe" means **prominence**:

[image]

Isolation is the distance to the next point with the same height (radius) of a higher mountain. So the nearest higher mountain seen from B is A, see the distance marked as "Dominanz".

Prominence is the difference from the peak to the next key col to which you have to descend *at least* to be able to reach a higher peak. So from summit B you have to descend at least to the col between B-C, therefore the marked "Schartenhöhe". The col between B-B' is not relevant because B is the higher peak.

Comment: Great. Looks perfect, as always, Everything Right Place!

Comment: @WedaPashi Thx and LOL :)

Comment: The col between B-B' is somewhat relevant - you'd measure the prominence of *B'* from that one.

Answer (score 8):

### Prominence

Is it's height above the surrounding ground (so the ground level is `x` height above sea level, the mounting is `y` height above sea level, it's `Prominence = y -x`)

### Isolation

Is the distance between it and the nearest point at the same height.

This is all based on the "footprint" on a map of a peak. This can be straight forward, or it can be very complicated.